# What is this plant with pink flowers and maple tree shaped leaves?

Tags: species-identification, botany

This plant goes in my front yard in morning sun in the interior of British Columbia.

[image]

It has green leaves initially and then they curl brown and turn yellow. It gets water weekly but not lots. Is it okay to divide this plant to thin it out?

Answer (score 2):

It's a Japanese Anemone [(Anemone hupehensis)](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=h310); if I had to guess, I'd guess it was the cultivar "Robustissima".

[image]

I used to grow these when I had gardens. Absolutely you can divide them! Wait until the spring if you can; if you have to divide in the fall, wait as long as you can to do so.

Comment: What kind of climate can these grow in? I really like them..

Comment: I love them; they're easy to grow , they last long, the seedheads are charming, and they're hardy perennials. What's not to like? They're hardy in zones 4 - 8.

Comment: thanks so much for figuring it out for us.  It is beautiful and looks like the hot location in the garden means it needs more water so the leaves don't turn brown.